# Scheduling one-off Tasks with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, queue, scheduled-tasks

I am currently trying to work out the best logic for a particular bit of functionality within my application.

Consider this:

1. A record is created in a database
2. 5 hours later, that record is deleted. Unless, it has been updated since it was created, in which case, the deletion will occur 5 hours after the `updated_at` time

I am very familiar with Laravel queues and cron jobs etc, and I have taken a brief look through Laravel Task Scheduler, but what I am actually struggling with is the logic of how this should work...

Here is my current algorithm (I know it is not the best solution):

1. Record is created in the database
2. A task is scheduled for this specific record 4 hours 55 minutes after the record was created *(the purpose of this is to send a notification to the user to warn them their record is about to be deleted)*
3. When the task executes, it will retrieve the record and ensure that the record has not been updated. If it has been updated, it will reset the task to 4 hours 55 minutes from the `updated_at` timestamp. If it hasn't been updated, it will run the same task again 5 minutes later where it will test the timestamp one more time before finally deleting the record.
4. Once the record has been deleted, the task will also be deleted

My concern with the above solution is that there are likely to be an enormous amount of records in the database, and therefore this will lead to an extremely large amount of tasks in the schedule which is probably not the best idea...

Can anyone suggest better logic than the above?

***Please note, I do not need the code to be written for me, I am simply looking for some assistance with the logic***

Answer (score 0):

I may be over simplifying this, but would the below process be simpler:

1. Record is created in database
2. Task is scheduled to run every minute

   - This task is looking for records with an `updated_at` value greater than or equal to the current time - I would just use `Carbon` for this - and deletes them from there

This would eliminate the need for queues and would just run solely on the task scheduler. Depending on the number of records you are dealing with you may need to schedule your tasks so that they don't overlap - however with a local database connection and some efficient code you could churn through a large number of records in a minute...

Would that work better?

Comment: I actually thought of this myself as well but the obvious problem is the fact that executing a query on the database every minute is not the best of ideas. In addition, something I haven't mentioned in order to keep this simple, checking to see if the item has been updated is not as simple as executing an SQL query. The database record was for example purposes :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a queued job, Laravel allows you to specify how long it is before it is processed again by the handler. See "Manually Releasing Jobs" on the link below.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#job-class-structure

You can then create some form of queued job and check when the updated_at time is plus however much time and then compare it to the current time and release it to the queue for that amount of seconds, meaning it should be run once or twice depending on if the updated_at changes, thus minimising the need to check the database.

`$this->release($timeUntilFiveHoursAfterUpdatedAt);`

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, as I mentioned in my question, I am more than familiar with how Laravel queues work etc. I cannot see a way in which I can delay a queue item by 5 hours, and I cannot how `release` helps in any way whatsoever...

Comment: Hey, so according to the docs, "The release method accepts one argument: the number of seconds you wish to wait until the job is made available again", so if you passed in 5 hours in theory it should make the job available to a handler at that point to then check if the updated at has changed and behave accordingly.